# Where did I go wrong with vue-router configuration, or the problem is somewhere in my component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have list of users which I output in Home vue component. Every item in the list is coming from vuex and has it's own details. When I click any of this contacts list items vue-router takes me to route /contact/that-item-id for example contact/4536475. Now, when I am on that page for specific contact list item and refresh my browser vue app breaks, in other words I don't have access to that specific item object properties anymore. 
Here is the code of my router

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "/",
      name: "Home",
      component: Home
    },
    {
      path: "/contact/:id",
      name: "ContactDetails",
      props: true,
      component: ContactDetails
```

I am setting props property to true so I can pass it as params to contact item details component as so:

```
<router-link
   class="view-more-btn"
   :to="{ name: 'ContactDetails', params: { id: contact.id }}"
>VIEW DETAILS</router-link>
```

and at last I am passing that Id to my getters method in vuex to get details for clicked item as this:

```
export default {
  props: ["id"],
  computed: {
    contact() {
      return this.$store.getters.getContactDetails(this.id);
    }
  }
```

Where did I go wrong, why I can't refresh my contact item detail page and still preserve state I am using.

I am new to vue so please forgive me if I am not making sence. And ofcourse any help is welcomed, thanks in advance

Comment: I don't quite understand what the problem is, but if it's about keeping the information, there's keep-alive if you can explain it to me better.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably, that you're referencing a named route and passing in the params by hand. This won't change the actual route displayed in your browsers address bar and only show the root path (`/contact/` in your example I presume). Therefore when you refresh the passed in params/props simply don't exist anymore.

What you need to do instead is use a `<router-link :to="'/contact/'+contact.id">` or `` <router-link :to="`/contact/${contact.id}`""> ``.

This should affect the URL in your browsers address bar to include the `/contact/someID123` which will then also make the ID available on refresh.

Comment: But how can I then have access to that specific id (in my case I pass it as router params)  which I need to get data for that item from store, that is I need it to render that specific data bound to that id in my detail component

Comment: The id will be available in your component as a property since you configured your route with `path: '/contact/:id` and `props: true`.

Comment: Then provide a codesandbox or jsfiddle showcasing your example, otherwise we can't help.

Comment: I have this in github repo https://github.com/MarkoCvrljak/vue-contact-book-app